# Google Analytics in AAR files: Class not found exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-analytics, google-play-services

I've developed an android library using google analytics and I'm successfully able to compile in a .aar file.

Such .aar file is later used into an Android Project, but once I run my application run I receive the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics"
```

In the library project, GA are imported as the official documentation describes:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
}
```

and later

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
```

My idea is that, somehow, the GA library is not exported with the aar.
Since these are my first tries within the Gradle world, does someone have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: As I was using in App build.gradle: 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0' and it was working like charm with out any additional code in Project build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the GA library is not exported.
Please try to export it.

Normally,to solve this exception, you must check the class name, then correct it or check if that class is in the classpath.